# Implement ZMOVE with WATCH in Redis

Tags: set, atomic, redis, sortedset

The [Redis documentation on transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) gives an example of how to implement ZPOP. How do I [implement ZMOVE for Redis sorted sets](http://code.google.com/p/redis/issues/detail?id=164) (analagous to [SMOVE](http://redis.io/commands/smove))?

Answer (score 0):

Is this right? .. to move an element, `ele`, from sorted set `z1` to `z2` and give it SCORE 1, i.e.:

```
ZMOVE z1 z2 1 ele

WATCH z1 z2
MULTI
ZREM z1 ele
ZADD z2 1 ele
EXEC
```

I will set the SCORE to be the current time, but I just used 1 here for simplicity.